# Which OpenGL version is the first to support Uniform Array of Structures?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I would like to use a Light struct in glsl, and define an array of them as a uniform variable like this:

```
uniform Light lights[LIGHT_NUM];
```

Unfortunately I was not able to find, which OpenGL/glsl/GL ES version do I need, to use this feature.

Comment: Why did you vote this question down?

Comment: For me this question reads like "This is not working for me, which version do I have to use to get it working?" in which case you didn't supply enough information. In addition, you ask for "OpenGL/glsl/GL ES" which makes it rather unclear for which OpenGL you want an answer.

Comment: I wanted to know about the support in older GL versions, before I use this feature, but I havent found any information about it. I wanted to get an answer for both GL, GL ES, and glsl, because features that are part of the GL spec, are not necessarily part of ES. Nicol gave the correct answer, that it is core since GL 2.0 and GLSL 1.10

Answer (score 5):

All of them. There is no version of GLSL, even [1.10](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.10.pdf) back from the GL 2.0 days, which does not support `uniform`s that are declared as structures and/or arrays. So long as `LIGHT_NUM` is a constant expression, and that the uniform is not too big for the implementation, then that will work in any version of GLSL.